# MySQL problem generating json_object without comma

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I'm trying to convert query into a json file but it does not includes comma at the end of each row.

Query

```
SELECT json_object("NumeroDetallePedido",d.idpedido,"PrecioUnidad",d.preciounidad,"Cantidad",d.cantidad,"Descuento",d.descuento, "Producto",json_array("NombreProducto",pro.nombreProducto),"Pedidos",json_array("FechaPedido",pe.FechaPedido)) 
  FROM detallesdepedidos d
  JOIN productos pro 
    ON d.idproducto = pro.idproducto 
  JOIN pedidos pe 
    ON d.idpedido = pe.IdPedido 
  INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/detallespedido_v4.json'
```

Result
{"Pedidos": ["FechaPedido", "1994-09-20"], "Cantidad": 45, "Producto": ["NombreProducto", "Té Dharamsala"], "Descuento": 0, "PrecioUnidad": 14, "NumeroDetallePedido": 10285}
{"Pedidos": ["FechaPedido", "1994-09-30"], "Cantidad": 18, "Producto": ["NombreProducto", "Té Dharamsala"], "Descuento": 0, "PrecioUnidad": 14, "NumeroDetallePedido": 10294}
{"Pedidos": ["FechaPedido", "1994-10-31"], "Cantidad": 20, "Producto": ["NombreProducto", "Té Dharamsala"], "Descuento": 0, "PrecioUnidad": 14, "NumeroDetallePedido": 10317}

it's not separated by commas ! Any ideas?

Thank u

Comment: where do you expect commas?

Comment: At the end of each row, the result it's making differents json_objects and I looking for an jsonArray with all the results

Answer (score 2):

Please, try with below query using JSON_ARRAYAGG:

```
SELECT 
JSON_ARRAYAGG(
  json_object(
        "NumeroDetallePedido", d.idpedido, "PrecioUnidad", d.preciounidad, "Cantidad", d.cantidad, "Descuento", d.descuento, "Producto",
        json_array("NombreProducto", pro.nombreProducto), "Pedidos", json_array("FechaPedido",pe.FechaPedido)
    ) 
)
FROM detallesdepedidos d 
INNER JOIN productos pro ON d.idproducto = pro.idproducto 
INNER JOIN pedidos pe ON d.idpedido = pe.IdPedido)
```

Comment: I had and error, FUNCTION neptuno.JSON_ARRAYAGG does not exist.

Comment: What's version of mysql.

Comment: MySQL 5.7.22 and later supports two aggregate JSON functions JSON_ARRAYAGG() and JSON_OBJECTAGG()

Answer (score 0):

select 
    concat('[',
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'name_field', name_field
                ,'address_field', address_field
                ,'contact_age', contact_age
                )
            SEPARATOR ',')
    ,']')
    from contact;

I was looking for this.